# How to detect if any app has been upgraded from it's base version installed in device and detect if it is a home launcher app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

How Can I detect that any system app (Pre Installed) in android is upgraded from its base package?

As well as , I want to know that Does package contain at least one activity that handles the home intent filter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution .

To detect if any system app has been upgraded from its base version-

```
List<PackageInfo> applications = getPackageManager()
        .getInstalledPackages(0);
  for (PackageInfo info : applications) {
     long firstInstalled = info.firstInstallTime;
     long lastUpdate = info.lastUpdateTime;

     try {
        ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
              info.applicationInfo.packageName, 0);
        if ((ai.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0 /*Check system app*/
              && firstInstalled != lastUpdate /*check for updated */) {
           Log.i(TAG,
                 "Upgraded pre installed app is "
                       + info.applicationInfo
                             .loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
        }

     } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("The exception is"+e.getMessage());
     }
  }
```

even There is one more option to check this using ..

```
if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) != 0)
{
    // APP WAS INSTALL AS AN UPDATE TO A BUILD-IN SYSTEM APP
}
```

To Detect Home Launcher apps-

```
  final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
  mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
  List<ResolveInfo> rinf = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
        mainIntent, 0);
  if (rinf != null) {
     for (ResolveInfo ri : rinf) {
        ActivityInfo ai = ri.activityInfo;
        if (ai == null) {
           continue;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "The Home Launcher Activity is  " + ai.packageName);

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first one you can just go to Settings and check if it gives you the option to Uninstall or just to Uninstall updates (meaning this apk is in the system).

The second one I would connect the device and check the Logcat.

In code:
Get the package and its [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html), there you can access to its lastUpdateTime and its firstInstallTime. About the second one, I dont know but share it if you find how, please :)

Comment: I want to know programmatically ?